# Link small images to big images

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, directory, glob

I would like to make a gallery. I have to folder, one with small images for the thumbnails and one with big images for the lightbox. I would like to link the thumbnails to the big images. How do I do that. I found following script and I pasted a script I would like to have it look like (the problem is it doesn't work like that).

I usually don't code with PHP thats why I ask, I guess theres a way to save the links in an array.

The PHP I found

```
<?php 
  foreach(glob('./images/small/*.*') as $file_small){
    echo "<img src='".$file_small."' />";
  }
?>
```

The PHP I would like

```
 <?php 
      foreach(glob('./images/small/*.*') as $file_small and glob('./images/big/*.*') as $file_big){
        echo "<a href='".$file_big."'><img src='".$file_small."' /></a>";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: why dont you use phpThumb for generating thumbnails rather than saving a thumbnail separately for each image???

Comment: @shahbaz Why would you make the server work to make thumbs when thousands of client computers can make them using the canvas ?

Comment: @Virus721 thats another option...

Comment: @shahbaz thanks. But do you know of a way using an own php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `phpThumb` http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ for generating thumbnails and use the php code like this :

```
<?php 
  foreach(glob('./images/big/*.*') as $file_big){
    echo "<a href='".$file_big."'><img src='phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../".$file_big."' /></a>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I didn't know phpthumb. Thank you. But I still wonder if there is a way making an own PHP script